# Computer stopped working (ASUS P5GD1-VM)

Tags: windows-xp, troubleshooting, intel-pentium

My computer stopped working the other day.  I came down and it was kind of chirping away.  Then, when I restarted it, it only did the same thing.

I unplugged everything not needed and it did nothing at all.  I thought maybe the power supply wasn't working, but when I took the cover off the green light on the motherboard was on and the power supply is making a little buzzing sound.  But nothing happens when I turn the computer on, other than the green light on the motherboard flickers a bit.

I checked the memory in other computer and it works fine.  I'd love to be able to fix this with as little cost as possible.  Can someone here help?

P4-640 (3.2E GHz, 800 FSB, L2:2MB, EM64T, HT)

Comment: You might want to add some more details, like what you were doing previously on the computer, if you've tried a LiveCD, etc.

Comment: Try clearing the CMOS memory, usually using a jumper on the motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

Like Josh K says, you need to figure out if you can actually boot the machine to see if the components work.  For example, if you can boot a Linux CD (freely available on the web) and run Linux, then maybe you have some Windows issues.  I would also try to boot in safe mode (F8, I believe, while starting up) and troubleshoot from there.  You need to narrow it down to software or hardware before you can really fix anything.